# "Old German" birth certificate from 1840 translation

Tags: german-to-english

Birth certificate from 1840 written in "Old German" presumed to be Carolingian Miniscule or Fraktur 15, I am unable to find someone to translate the complete certificate.  It is unknown where birth occurred.[image]

Comment: Do you want a transcription or a translation?

Comment: Well no - that's not "Karolingische Minuskel", that's written in plain Fraktur, basically the go-to font for 19th century printed matter.

Comment: We don't offer bulk proof reading and translation requests. If you struggle with a specific word, you may ask for help, but such requests won't help anyone else with a similar question. Many readers here have the knowledge to answer such requests, but it is against the intention of the site.

Comment: The *Carolingian minuscule* is a script that developed in the 8th century from other scripts, which in turn had the Latin script of the ancient Roman Empire as their root. It was widely used during the reign of Charlemagne (from whom it takes its name). As in all other scripts that existed at that time and before, there were no upper and lower case letters. Therefore, if you see upper and lower case letters together in a word, it cannot ...

Comment: ... be Carolingian minuscule. In the 12th century, the Carolingian minuscule developed into the Gothic script, which also did not yet know upper and lower case letters. But soon it became fashionable to mix the everyday Gothic script with a script that was already about 2000 years old at that time: it was mixed with the old Latin script that was in use in ancient Rome. At first, the letters of the ancient Latin script were used only for large and beautifully decorated initials, but soon the initials of ...

Comment: ... all important words were written with the ancient Latin script (but in normal size and without decoration), while all other letters were written in Gothic letters. This corresponds pretty much to the titlecase in modern English headings, and it is also the reason why in German texts all nouns are still written with a capital initial. And so the two fonts, each with 26 glyphs, merged into a new typeface that still had 26 letters, but now had ...

Comment: ... 52 glyphs: 2 glyphs per letter (with a few exceptions). When letterpress printing was invented, printers kept their letters (which were made of lead) in two cases of wood, divided into small compartments. The smaller Gothic letters, which were needed more often, were placed in the lower case, which was closer to the printer's workstation. The old and larger Latin letters, which they needed less often, were kept a little further away in the upper case. That is where the names upper and lower case letters come from.

Comment: Also, it's not appropriate to state the document was *written in "Old German"*. Althochdeutsch was an early phase of the German language, around 750-1050 AD. Yes, the document is written (printed) in an old (typically German) **typeface**. And yes, the style is certainly **dated**. But from a linguistic standpoint you would call this "New (High) German" (Neuhochdeutsch) and not "Old German".

Comment: @MichaelBoss: Did we answer your question satisfactorily? If so, please mark the answer as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark symbol you can see beside it.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a birth certificate. It's a "Tauf-Zedel", a more elaborate version of a greeting card commemorating the baptism of a child. It's from the ["Taufgöte"](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/taufgote), which is an old (obsolete) word for godparent, directed to the child. I'm having trouble reading the handwriting but I don't think the place of birth is mentioned.

Here is a transcription of the text and a translation.

Upper left:

> Herr! Dir sey das Kind ergeben, schenk ihm Gnad zum frommen Leben, daß es nach der Jammerzeit, werd ein Erb der Seligkeit.

Translation: *Lord! May the child be meek, gift him mercy for a pious life, so that after life in misery* [Jammerzeit is literally "time of lamentation, misery, sorrow", i.e. an image for life as imagined in the mid 1800s] *it become an heir of salvation.*

Upper right:

> Christus spricht: Lasset die Kindlein zu mir kommen und wehret es ihnen nicht. Denn solchen ist das Himmelreich.

Translation: *Christ speaks* [this is a direct quote of Matthew 19:14]: *Let the little children come to me, and do not hinder them, for the kingdom of heaven belongs to such as these.*

Middle:

> Höchster Gott! Ach lass doch kommen, Deinen Segen auf dies Kind! Schreib es in die Zahl der Frommen, die im Buch des Lebens sind; wasch es ab mit deinem Blut, von allen Sünden rein: Damit es möge Gott und Menschen wohlgefällig sein.
>
> Dieses wünschet dein allgetreuste[r] Tauf Götti
>
> Niklaus Andres von Aetigen[?]
>
> Den 5. Tag Jenners im Jahr 1840
>
> bist du worden getauft, durchs Blut Jesu theuer erkauft; darum lebe ihm allein, so wird er auch dein Vater seyn! Amen.

Translation: *Highest God! O let your blessing come upon this child. Let it* [switch from masculine to neuter in German] *be numbered* [i.e. included in] *among the pious that are in the book of life; wash all its sins away with your blood so that it please God and its fellow men.*

*This wishes your most faithful godfather* [Götti is alemannic] *Niklaus Andres from Aetigen*[?].†
*On the 5th day of January in the year 1840 you were baptised, won at great cost with the blood of Jesus; therefore live for him alone, and he will be father also to you.*

†There is a village by the name of Aetingen (also Aetigen) in the canton of Solothurn, Switzerland ([wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aetingen)); formerly in the canton of Bern, as in [this](https://www.helveticarchives.ch/detail.aspx?ID=481086) document from 1824.

Lower left:

> Ihr Kinder seyd gehorsam euern Eltern in dem Herrn. Denn das ist billig.

Translation: *You children, be obedient to your parents in the Lord. For this is just.*

Lower right:

> Liebes Kind, lebe so auf Erden, daß du mögest selig werden.

Translation: *Dear child, live on earth in such a way that you may be blessed.*

Comment: The word "Tauf-Zedel" seems to be an outdated variant of "Taufzettel". This is a Swiss form of "[Patenbrief](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patenbrief)" (godfather letter).

Comment: If it is an old godfather letter, then it is not surprising that neither the child's name nor place and date of the birth are mentioned,, but only the godfather''s name. and the baptism date.